# How do I disable a GtkMenuItem?

Tags: linux, gtk

I have a menu item that I would like to disable if certain conditions are met.
In other words, prevent it from being clicked.  Still visible but the usual greyed out or similar.

The menu is built up manually similar to this:

```
void menu_action(GtkMenuItem* menuitem, gpointer menu_id){
  printf("You selected menu id: %d\n", GPOINTER_TO_INT(menu_id));
}

void make_menu(){
  GtkWidget *menu  = gtk_menu_new();
  GtkWidget *login = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Login");
  GtkWidget *quit  = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Quit");

  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), login);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), quit);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(login), "activate", G_CALLBACK(menu_action), GINT_TO_POINTER(-100));
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quit), "activate", G_CALLBACK(menu_action), GINT_TO_POINTER(-101));
}
```

Lets just assume, Login was selected.  What I want to do is perform the login action, change the menu item label to be the username of the person logged in, and then disable it so that it can't be clicked.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They opted to use the word 'sensitive' to describe this behavior:

```
gtk_widget_set_sensitive(login, FALSE);
gtk_menu_item_set_label(GTK_MENU_ITEM(login), "Logged In: Matt");
```

Comment: Sounds like they went politically correct on that, disabled to sensitive.  Weird.  It's not a word that comes to mind.  Even inactive would have been a better choice.  Oh well, thanks for that it works perfectly!

Comment: Alternatively make use of GAction and set the action to disabled.